# pam_ssh_agent_auth: sudo asks for password with ssh user@host, but ssh user@host 'bash' not

Tags: ssh, sudo, password, pam

I use gpg-agent to manage ssh-agent.

On my PC: `ssh-add -L` prints my public keys which is used on the server. `ForwardAgent` is open. `pam.d/sudo` and `sudoers` are configured.

After `ssh user@host`, `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` print the gpg-agent one. If running `sudo -i` or other command with `sudo`, it asks password.

If using `ssh user@host 'bash'` or other shell, then `sudo` can run without asking password. By the way, this method will not print any prompt of shell, such as `$` .

Set `pam.d/sudo` with `auth ... debug`, and get the log:

```
Nov 10 16:46:23 nixos sudo[30150]: pam_ssh_agent_auth: Beginning pam_ssh_agent_auth for user vonfry
Nov 10 16:46:23 nixos sudo[30150]: pam_ssh_agent_auth: Attempting authentication: `vonfry' as `vonfry' using ~/.ssh/authorized_keys:~/.ssh/authorized_keys2:/etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/%u
Nov 10 16:46:23 nixos sudo[30150]: pam_ssh_agent_auth: Contacted ssh-agent of user vonfry (1000)
Nov 10 16:46:23 nixos gpg-agent[4022]: scdaemon[4022]: pcsc_establish_context failed: no service (0x8010001d)
Nov 10 16:46:23 nixos sudo[30150]: pam_ssh_agent_auth: Failed Authentication: `vonfry' as `vonfry' using ~/.ssh/authorized_keys:~/.ssh/authorized_keys2:/etc/ssh/authorized_keys.d/%u
```

On the server, `gpg-agent` is listed in htop owned by my ssh login user and `gpg-connect-agent` can work. `TTY` and `GPG_TTY` are the same.

`htop` showed `gpg-agent` has a subprocess `scdaemon --multi-server`

I tried to search around `gpg-agent[4022]: scdaemon[4022]: pcsc_establish_context failed: no service (0x8010001d)`, but got nothing useful.

EDIT1:
If I kill the ssh login user's gpg-agent daemon, the sudo can work without password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason. My interactive shell script re-export the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable which override the original one from sshd.